# check if any part of the circle drawn visible in the screen

Tags: java, javafx

In my application, I'm drawing a lot of circles of different radii on a javafx canvas using the `fillOval` and `strokeOval` methods. I am trying to optimize this draw operation by drawing only those circles which will be visible(partially also) in my screen. So I want to know is there a method that can tell me that drawing this circle, text, line, image etc. will be visible in the screen.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    Pane pane;
    Canvas canvas;
    double transX = 0.0, transY = 0.0;

    public void draw() {
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.clearRect(canvas.getLayoutX(), canvas.getLayoutY(), canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        gc.setStroke(Color.FIREBRICK);
        gc.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        gc.setLineWidth(2.0);

        for(int i = 1; i <= 10000; ++i) {
            double r = 10 * i;
            // some function to check the below drawing operations will be visible or not
            // Pls. note centre of the circles need not be at the centre of the screen, if canvas is panned to right/left/top/bottom by mouse drag operation where translation values will be stored in transX and transY
            gc.fillOval(pane.getWidth() / 2 - r + transX, pane.getHeight() / 2 - r + transY, 2 * r, 2 * r);
            gc.strokeOval(pane.getWidth() / 2 - r + transX, pane.getHeight() / 2 - r + transY, 2 * r, 2 * r);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        pane = new Pane();
        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.layoutXProperty().bind(pane.layoutXProperty());
        canvas.layoutYProperty().bind(pane.layoutYProperty());
        canvas.widthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());
        canvas.heightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());

        pane.widthProperty().addListener((observableValue, number, t1) -> draw());

        pane.heightProperty().addListener((observableValue, number, t1) -> draw());

        pane.getChildren().addAll(canvas);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, primaryStage.getWidth(), primaryStage.getHeight()));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Canvas Demo");
        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could do it yourself by checking if the circle is more than one radius left of the left edge, or right of the right edge, or above the top edge, or below the bottom edge, but I don't know if there's an API call to do that.

Comment: If you would use the scene graph instead of the Canvas class you would get that functionality for free.